# How to avoid using a global variable, when closing an EventSource in internal links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, internal

I have a web application, where some internal pages use an EventSource to receive live updates from the server.

The client code looks like this:

```
var LiveClient = (function() {
    return {
        live: function(i) {
            var source = new EventSource("/stream/tick");
            source.addEventListener('messages.keepalive', function(e) {
                console.log("Client "+ i + ' received a message.');
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

You can see a live demo on heroku: http://eventsourcetest.herokuapp.com/test/test/1. If you open the developer console, you will see a message printed every time an event is received.

The problem is that when visiting internal links, the EventSource remains open, causing messages to be printed even after the visitor moves from one page to another - so if you visit the three links on the top, you will get messages from three sources.

How can I close the previous connection after the user moves from one internal page to another?

A hacky workaround that I tried was to use a global variable for the EventSource object, like this:

```
var LiveClient = (function() {
    return {
        live_global: function(i) {
            // We set source as global, otherwise we were left
            // with sources remaining open after visiting internal
            // pages
            if (typeof source != "undefined" && source != null) {
                if (source.OPEN) {
                    source.close();
                    console.log("Closed source");
                }
            }
            source = new EventSource("/stream/tick");
            source.addEventListener('messages.keepalive', function(e) {
                console.log("Client "+ i + ' received a message.');
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

Demo here: http://eventsourcetest.herokuapp.com/test/test_global/1, but I am looking for a solution that would avoid the use of a global variable if possible.

The HTML code that is generated is:

```
  <a href="/test/test_global/1">Page 1</a> |
  <a href="/test/test_global/2">Page 2</a> |
  <a href="/test/test_global/3">Page 3</a> |

<p>This is page 3</p>
<script>
  $(function() {
    LiveClient.live_global(3);
  });
</script>
```

or with `LiveClient.live_global(1);` for the case with the global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I haven't tested it. If it works, you might be able to replace `LiveClient.source` with `this.source` which is a lot cleaner imo.

```
  var LiveClient = (function() {
    return {
        source: null,
        live_global: function(i) {
            // We set source as global, otherwise we were left
            // with sources remaining open after visiting internal
            // pages
            if (typeof LiveClient.source != "undefined" && LiveClient.source != null) {
                if (source.OPEN) {
                    source.close();
                    console.log("Closed source");
                }
            }
            LiveClient.source = new EventSource("/stream/tick");
            LiveClient.source.addEventListener('messages.keepalive', function(e) {
                console.log("Client "+ i + ' received a message.');
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Yup, this did it, both with `LiveClient.source` and with `this.source`. Thanks a ton :)